# How do we make questions like "What do I do when I get to Destination X?" good for the site?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I see any number of such questions, that basically vary with regard to destination. A few of them are answerable. Most of them get closed. What separates the first group from the second? Some ideas that I had:

1) Give a clear idea of your interests. Are you an outdoors/indoors type? Do you want to be an active participant or just a spectator? Are you looking to do something "traditional" or off the beaten track?"

2) Give a clear idea of budget constraints. Are you looking to save money or be a big spender.

3) Give a clear idea of transportation issues. Are you going to rely on local transportation, or provide your own.

4) Who are the members of the group? Are we dealing with one person (you) are are there multiple interests to be taken care of? Are group members quite similar or very different?

5) Age isn't usually an important factor, unless you're very old (with mobility problems) or very young (asked for ID everywhere you go). Still, it could be a factor in determining who you are. And dietary, health, medical, and similar constraints do figure into the equation--at any age.

Is a question that covers most of these areas a good question? Are there other important areas I haven't covered?

Comment: See also: [What are good *on-topic* basic questions about a destination?](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/38/what-are-good-on-topic-basic-questions-about-a-destination) and [Are 'recommendation' questions on topic?](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/6/are-recommendation-questions-on-topic)

Comment: sometimes these guidelines are hard to live with. i really want to find "recommendation" lists here.

Answer (score 5):

Basically some questions that might be very broad would break either or both of the "subjective" or "no one right answer" rules.

So the more specifics you include in the question the narrower it gets so that we don't have to have a dozen answers covering all possible tastes to have a chance of hitting upon the advice being looked for.